# Can't find Infinitest Stack Trace in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, stack-trace, infinitest

Infinitest is running and showing me the failed test marker, and when I hover over the marker I get text that reads `NullPointerException()`, but I can't find out how to view the full stack trace to know where the exception is being thrown.

[image: Failed Test Marker]

Comment: doesn't you get the exception trace printed on console?

Comment: I do if I manually run the test, but not if the test is run by Infinitest. I'd rather not have to manually run the tests to see the stack trace because, you know, that sort of defeats the purpose of having a continuous test runner...